# Tengo problemas con ciertas librerias C

Tags: c, algoritmos

Estoy haciendo mi proyecto de la universidad y estoy creando varias librerias, entre ellas tengo estas

```
#include "menus.h"
#include "usuario.h"
#include "listaMaterias.h"
#include "validacion.h"
```

El problema que tengo es que la libreria `"validacion.h"` la estoy usando también en las librerias `"usuario.h"` y `"listaMaterias.h"` y cuando compilo mi programa principal me marca unos errores referentes a la librería de `"validacion.h"` pero no se como resolverlo.

```
In file included from listaMaterias.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:5:
validacion.h:12:6: error: redefinition of ‘validarNumero’
 bool validarNumero(char numero[])
      ^
In file included from usario.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:4:
validacion.h:12:6: note: previous definition of ‘validarNumero’ was here
 bool validarNumero(char numero[])
      ^
In file included from listaMaterias.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:5:
validacion.h:33:6: error: redefinition of ‘validarLetras’
 bool validarLetras(char nombre[])
      ^
In file included from usario.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:4:
validacion.h:33:6: note: previous definition of ‘validarLetras’ was here
 bool validarLetras(char nombre[])
      ^
In file included from listaMaterias.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:5:
validacion.h:54:6: error: redefinition of ‘validarFecha’
 bool validarFecha(char dia[], char mes[], char ano[])
      ^
In file included from usario.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:4:
validacion.h:54:6: note: previous definition of ‘validarFecha’ was here
 bool validarFecha(char dia[], char mes[], char ano[])
```

Estos son los errores que me salen.

Esta es la libreria `"listaMaterias.h"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "validacion.h"

struct actividades
{
    char tipoDeActividad[22];
    char diaDeLaSemana[12];
    char horaDeIncio[8];
    char horaDeFin[8];
    char salon[10];
};

struct materias
{
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];
    struct actividades *actividad;
    struct fechasEspeciales *fechas;
    struct materias *siguiente;
};

typedef struct materias _nodoMaterias;
typedef struct fechasEspeciales _nodoFechasEspeciales;

_nodoMaterias *crearListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
bool listaVacia(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *insetarEnListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
void imprimirLista (_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *crearNodoMaterias(char nombre[], char profesor[], char tipoDeMateria[], char horasSemanales[]);
void datosAlumno();
_nodoMaterias *eliminarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
bool buscarMateria(char nombre[], _nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *modificarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);

//AQUI SE CREA LISTA Y SE PONE PARA QUE APUNTE A NULL
_nodoMaterias *crearListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    return (apuntador = NULL);
}

//ESTA FUNCION VERIFICA SI LA LISTA ESTA VACIA 
bool listaVacia(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    if (apuntador == NULL)
        return (true); //SI SALE EL TRUE SIGNIFICA QUE LA LISTA ESTA VACIA
    else
        return (false);//SI SALE EL FALSE SIGNIFICA QUE LA LISTA NO ESTA VACIA 
}

//AQUI SE CREA EL NUEVO NODO DE LA LISTA
_nodoMaterias *crearNodoMaterias(char nombre[], char profesor[], char tipoDeMateria[], char horasSemanales[])
{
    _nodoMaterias *registroNuevo;

    registroNuevo = (_nodoMaterias *) malloc(sizeof(_nodoMaterias));

    printf("\n----NUEVA MATERIA----\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nombre);
    while(!validarLetras(nombre))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",nombre);

        /*while(!buscarMateria())*/
    }
    printf("PROFESOR: ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%s",profesor);
    while(!validarLetras(profesor))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nPROFESOR: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",profesor);
    }
    printf("TIPO DE MATERIA: ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
    while(!validarLetras(tipoDeMateria))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS");
        printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
    }
    printf("HORAS SEMANALES:  ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
    while(!validarNumero(horasSemanales))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
        printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
    }
    fflush(stdin);

        strcpy(registroNuevo->nombre, nombre);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->profesor, profesor);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->tipoDeMateria, tipoDeMateria);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->horasSemanales, horasSemanales);
        registroNuevo->siguiente = NULL;

    return registroNuevo;   

}

//AQUI SE INSERTA EL NODO EN LA LISTA LUGEO DE SER CREADO POR LA FUNCION crearNodo
_nodoMaterias *insetarEnListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *registroNuevo, *apuntadorAuxiliar;
    char respuesta,ch;
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];

    //ESTE CICLO SE ENCARGA DE QUE SE REPITA EL PORCESO PARA PODER INGRESAR MATERIAS HASTA QUE EL USUARIO DECIDA
    do
    {
            registroNuevo=crearNodoMaterias(nombre, profesor, tipoDeMateria, horasSemanales);
            if (listaVacia(apuntador)) 
                apuntador = registroNuevo;
            else
            {
                apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;
                while (apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente != NULL)
                    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
                apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = registroNuevo;
            }

            printf("\nPARA INGRESAR OTRA MATERIA MARQUE... 1");
            printf("\nPARA SALIR MARQUE... '0'\n");         
     while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');      

    scanf("%c", &respuesta);
        fflush(stdin);
   printf("RESPUESTA = %c", respuesta);             

    }while (respuesta == '1');
    return apuntador;
}

//TENGO QUE RIVAR BIEN LA FUNCION DE eliminarMateria PARA VER PQ NO ME ELIMINA LAS MATERIAS

_nodoMaterias *eliminarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    char materia[20];
    printf("\nQUE MATERIA DESEA ELIMINAR:  ");
    scanf("%s",materia);
    fflush(stdin);

    //INTENTO DE BORRAR NODO 1
    if (!listaVacia(apuntador))
    {
        _nodoMaterias *borrarAuxiliar;
        _nodoMaterias *anterior = NULL;

        while (apuntador != NULL)
        {
            /*anterior = borrarAuxiliar;
            borrarAuxiliar = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;*/
            if (strcmp(apuntador->nombre, materia) == 0)
            {
                anterior->siguiente = apuntador->siguiente;
                borrarAuxiliar = apuntador;
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
                free(borrarAuxiliar);
            }
            else
            {
                anterior = apuntador;
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
            }
        }
/*
        if (borrarAuxiliar == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nNODO NO ENCONTRADO");
        }else if (anterior == NULL)
            {
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
                free(borrarAuxiliar);               
            } else
                {
                    anterior->siguiente = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;
                    free(borrarAuxiliar);                   
                }*/
    }

    return apuntador;
}

_nodoMaterias *modificarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    char materia[20];
    printf("\nQUE MATERIA DESEA MODIFICAR:  ");
    scanf("%s",materia);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (!listaVacia(apuntador))
    {
        _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

        while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {           
            if (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL && strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) == 0)
            {
                char nombre[30];
                char profesor[30];
                char tipoDeMateria[20];
                char horasSemanales[10];

                printf("\nINGRESE LOS NUEVOS DATOS DE LA MATERIA");
                printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",nombre);
                while(!validarLetras(nombre))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
                    printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",nombre);
                }
                printf("PROFESOR: ");
                fflush(stdin);  
                scanf("%s",profesor);
                while(!validarLetras(profesor))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
                    printf("\nPROFESOR: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",profesor);
                }
                printf("TIPO DE MATERIA: ");
                fflush(stdin);  
                scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
                while(!validarLetras(tipoDeMateria))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS");
                    printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
                }
                printf("HORAS SEMANALES:  ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
                while(!validarNumero(horasSemanales))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
                    printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
                }
                fflush(stdin);

                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, nombre);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->profesor, profesor);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeMateria, tipoDeMateria);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->horasSemanales, horasSemanales);
                apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = NULL;
            }

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }

    }
    else
        printf("\nLA LISTA ESTA VACIA");

    return apuntador;
}

//IMPRIMIR LOS NODOS DE LA LISTA
void imprimirLista (_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        printf("NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN LA LISTA \n");
    else
    {
        while(apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {
            printf(" \n------------MATERIAS-------------- ");
            printf("\nNOMBRE: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre);
            printf("\nPROFESOR: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->profesor);
            printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeMateria);
            printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->horasSemanales);

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    }

    return;
}

//ESTA FUNCION LE PERMITE SABER AL USUARIO LAS MATERIAS QUE INSCRIBIO 
void imprimirListaDeMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    int contador;

    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        printf("NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN LA LISTA\n");
    else
    { 
        contador = 0;
        printf("\nLISTA DE MATERIAS REGISTRADAS\n"); //AQUI VAN APARECIENDO LAS MATERIAS EN ORDEN ASI EL USARIO SABE CUALES DEBE SELCCIONAR
        while(apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {
            contador++;
            printf("%d", contador);printf(".- %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre);

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    }

    return; 
}

bool buscarMateria(char materia[], _nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
    }

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;


}
```

Esta es la libreria `"usuario.h"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "validacion.h"

void datosAlumno(char nombre[], char apellido[], char cedula[], char telefono[], char carrera[]);

void datosAlumno(char nombre[], char apellido[], char cedula[], char telefono[], char carrera[])
{
    printf("\n INTRODUZCA EL NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO:     \n");
    scanf("%s", nombre);
    while(!validarLetras(nombre))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", nombre);
    }
    printf("\n INTRODUZCA EL APELLIDO DEL ALUMNO:     \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", apellido);
    while(!validarLetras(apellido))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nAPELLIDO: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", apellido);
    }
    printf("\n INTRODUZCA LA CEDULA DEL ALUMNO:     \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", cedula);
    while(!validarNumero(cedula))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", cedula);
    }
    printf("\n INTRODUZCA EL TELEFONO DEL ALUMNO:     \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", telefono);
    while(!validarNumero(telefono))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", telefono);
    }
    printf("\n INTRODUZCA LA CARRERA DEL ALUMNO:     \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", carrera);
    while(!validarLetras(carrera))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", carrera);
    }
    fflush(stdin);

    system("clear");
    printf("\n%s\n", nombre);
    printf("\n%s\n", apellido);
    printf("\n%s\n", cedula);
    printf("\n%s\n", telefono);
    printf("\n%s\n", carrera);
    getchar();
}
```

Esta es la libreria `"validacion.h"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool validarNumero(char numero[50]);
bool validarLetras(char nombre[50]);
bool validarFecha(char dia[], char mes[], char ano[]);

bool validarNumero(char numero[])
{
    int i = 0, j;

    j = strlen(numero);

    while (i < j)
    {
        if (isdigit(numero[i]) != 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool validarLetras(char nombre[])
{
    int i = 0, j;

    j = strlen(nombre);

    while (i < j)
    {
        if (isalpha(nombre[i]) != 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool validarFecha(char dia[], char mes[], char ano[])
{
    int month, day, year;

        day = atoi(dia);
        month = atoi(mes);
        year = atoi(ano);

    //Si el mes ingresado es Febrero, el año no es bisiesto y el día es mayor a 28 o menor o igual a cero
    if((month == 2) && !((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) && ((day > 28) || (day <= 0)))
    {
        printf("\n\nFecha incorrecta: Este mes solo tiene 28 dias");
        return false;
    }
    //Si el mes ingresado es Febrero, el año es bisiesto y el día es mayor a 29 o menor o igual a cero
    else if((month == 2) && ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) && ((day > 29) || (day <= 0)))
    {
        printf("\n\nFecha incorrecta: Este mes solo tiene 29 dias");
        return false;
    }
    //Si el mes es distinto a Febrero (cualquiera de los demás meses que tengan 31 días) y el día es mayor a 31 o menor o igual a cero
    else if(((month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) || (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12)) && ((day > 31) || (day <= 0)))
    {
        printf("\n\nFecha incorrecta: Este mes solo tiene 31 dias");
        return false;
    }
    //Si el mes es distinto a Febrero (cualquiera de los demás meses que tengan 30 días) y el día es mayor a 30 o menor o igual a cero
    else if(((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) && ((day > 30) || (day <= 0)))
    {
        printf("\n\nFecha incorrecta: Este mes solo tiene 30 dias");
        return false;
    }
    //Si el mes es mayor a 12 o menor o igual a cero
    else if((month > 12) || (month <= 0))
    {
        printf("\n\nFecha incorrecta: El año solo tiene 12 meses");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: ¿qué error te señala el compilador?

Comment: Si no escribes que error es el que obtienes, es difícil responder con una pregunta precisa.

Comment: @Elenasys edite la pregunta agregando los errores que me salen en el compilador

Comment: @eyllanesc edite la pregunta agregando los errores que me salen en el compilador

Comment: @ilfredo puedes mostrarnos los archivos .h

Comment: @eyllanesc cómo hago?? simplemente vuelvo a editar la pregunta y agrego los .h??

Comment: @ilfredo copia el código de los archivos en tu publicación

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes usar la guardas en los headers ya que cuando usas la instrucción #include el compilador copia los archivos a uno intermedio, por lo que causará el error, si usas #define y #ifdef el preprocesador impedirá que se repita las importaciones , es decir, por ejemplo del header archivo.h

```
#ifndef ARCHIVO_H
#define ARCHIVO_H

# tú código

.......

#endif // ARCHIVO_H
```

por ejemplo en "listaMaterias.h":

```
#ifndef LISTAMATERIAS_H
#define LISTAMATERIAS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "validacion.h"

struct actividades
{
    char tipoDeActividad[22];
    char diaDeLaSemana[12];
    char horaDeIncio[8];
    char horaDeFin[8];
    char salon[10];
};

struct materias
{
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];
    struct actividades *actividad;
    struct fechasEspeciales *fechas;
    struct materias *siguiente;
};

typedef struct materias _nodoMaterias;
typedef struct fechasEspeciales _nodoFechasEspeciales;

_nodoMaterias *crearListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
bool listaVacia(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *insetarEnListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
void imprimirLista (_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *crearNodoMaterias(char nombre[], char profesor[], char tipoDeMateria[], char horasSemanales[]);
void datosAlumno();
_nodoMaterias *eliminarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
bool buscarMateria(char nombre[], _nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *modificarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);

//AQUI SE CREA LISTA Y SE PONE PARA QUE APUNTE A NULL
_nodoMaterias *crearListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    return (apuntador = NULL);
}

//ESTA FUNCION VERIFICA SI LA LISTA ESTA VACIA 
bool listaVacia(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    if (apuntador == NULL)
        return (true); //SI SALE EL TRUE SIGNIFICA QUE LA LISTA ESTA VACIA
    else
        return (false);//SI SALE EL FALSE SIGNIFICA QUE LA LISTA NO ESTA VACIA 
}

//AQUI SE CREA EL NUEVO NODO DE LA LISTA
_nodoMaterias *crearNodoMaterias(char nombre[], char profesor[], char tipoDeMateria[], char horasSemanales[])
{
    _nodoMaterias *registroNuevo;

    registroNuevo = (_nodoMaterias *) malloc(sizeof(_nodoMaterias));

    printf("\n----NUEVA MATERIA----\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nombre);
    while(!validarLetras(nombre))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",nombre);

        /*while(!buscarMateria())*/
    }
    printf("PROFESOR: ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%s",profesor);
    while(!validarLetras(profesor))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nPROFESOR: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",profesor);
    }
    printf("TIPO DE MATERIA: ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
    while(!validarLetras(tipoDeMateria))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS");
        printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
    }
    printf("HORAS SEMANALES:  ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
    while(!validarNumero(horasSemanales))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
        printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
    }
    fflush(stdin);

        strcpy(registroNuevo->nombre, nombre);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->profesor, profesor);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->tipoDeMateria, tipoDeMateria);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->horasSemanales, horasSemanales);
        registroNuevo->siguiente = NULL;

    return registroNuevo;   

}

//AQUI SE INSERTA EL NODO EN LA LISTA LUGEO DE SER CREADO POR LA FUNCION crearNodo
_nodoMaterias *insetarEnListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *registroNuevo, *apuntadorAuxiliar;
    char respuesta,ch;
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];

    //ESTE CICLO SE ENCARGA DE QUE SE REPITA EL PORCESO PARA PODER INGRESAR MATERIAS HASTA QUE EL USUARIO DECIDA
    do
    {
            registroNuevo=crearNodoMaterias(nombre, profesor, tipoDeMateria, horasSemanales);
            if (listaVacia(apuntador)) 
                apuntador = registroNuevo;
            else
            {
                apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;
                while (apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente != NULL)
                    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
                apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = registroNuevo;
            }

            printf("\nPARA INGRESAR OTRA MATERIA MARQUE... 1");
            printf("\nPARA SALIR MARQUE... '0'\n");         
     while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');      

    scanf("%c", &respuesta);
        fflush(stdin);
   printf("RESPUESTA = %c", respuesta);             

    }while (respuesta == '1');
    return apuntador;
}

//TENGO QUE RIVAR BIEN LA FUNCION DE eliminarMateria PARA VER PQ NO ME ELIMINA LAS MATERIAS

_nodoMaterias *eliminarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    char materia[20];
    printf("\nQUE MATERIA DESEA ELIMINAR:  ");
    scanf("%s",materia);
    fflush(stdin);

    //INTENTO DE BORRAR NODO 1
    if (!listaVacia(apuntador))
    {
        _nodoMaterias *borrarAuxiliar;
        _nodoMaterias *anterior = NULL;

        while (apuntador != NULL)
        {
            /*anterior = borrarAuxiliar;
            borrarAuxiliar = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;*/
            if (strcmp(apuntador->nombre, materia) == 0)
            {
                anterior->siguiente = apuntador->siguiente;
                borrarAuxiliar = apuntador;
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
                free(borrarAuxiliar);
            }
            else
            {
                anterior = apuntador;
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
            }
        }
/*
        if (borrarAuxiliar == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nNODO NO ENCONTRADO");
        }else if (anterior == NULL)
            {
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
                free(borrarAuxiliar);               
            } else
                {
                    anterior->siguiente = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;
                    free(borrarAuxiliar);                   
                }*/
    }

    return apuntador;
}

_nodoMaterias *modificarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    char materia[20];
    printf("\nQUE MATERIA DESEA MODIFICAR:  ");
    scanf("%s",materia);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (!listaVacia(apuntador))
    {
        _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

        while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {           
            if (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL && strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) == 0)
            {
                char nombre[30];
                char profesor[30];
                char tipoDeMateria[20];
                char horasSemanales[10];

                printf("\nINGRESE LOS NUEVOS DATOS DE LA MATERIA");
                printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",nombre);
                while(!validarLetras(nombre))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
                    printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",nombre);
                }
                printf("PROFESOR: ");
                fflush(stdin);  
                scanf("%s",profesor);
                while(!validarLetras(profesor))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
                    printf("\nPROFESOR: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",profesor);
                }
                printf("TIPO DE MATERIA: ");
                fflush(stdin);  
                scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
                while(!validarLetras(tipoDeMateria))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS");
                    printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
                }
                printf("HORAS SEMANALES:  ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
                while(!validarNumero(horasSemanales))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
                    printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
                }
                fflush(stdin);

                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, nombre);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->profesor, profesor);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeMateria, tipoDeMateria);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->horasSemanales, horasSemanales);
                apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = NULL;
            }

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }

    }
    else
        printf("\nLA LISTA ESTA VACIA");

    return apuntador;
}

//IMPRIMIR LOS NODOS DE LA LISTA
void imprimirLista (_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        printf("NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN LA LISTA \n");
    else
    {
        while(apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {
            printf(" \n------------MATERIAS-------------- ");
            printf("\nNOMBRE: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre);
            printf("\nPROFESOR: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->profesor);
            printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeMateria);
            printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->horasSemanales);

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    }

    return;
}

//ESTA FUNCION LE PERMITE SABER AL USUARIO LAS MATERIAS QUE INSCRIBIO 
void imprimirListaDeMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    int contador;

    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        printf("NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN LA LISTA\n");
    else
    { 
        contador = 0;
        printf("\nLISTA DE MATERIAS REGISTRADAS\n"); //AQUI VAN APARECIENDO LAS MATERIAS EN ORDEN ASI EL USARIO SABE CUALES DEBE SELCCIONAR
        while(apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {
            contador++;
            printf("%d", contador);printf(".- %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre);

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    }

    return; 
}

bool buscarMateria(char materia[], _nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
    }

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

#endif //LISTAMATERIAS_H
```

Otra recomendación es separa la implementación de la declaración, es decir:

```
#ifndef LISTAMATERIAS_H
#define LISTAMATERIAS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "validacion.h"

struct actividades
{
    char tipoDeActividad[22];
    char diaDeLaSemana[12];
    char horaDeIncio[8];
    char horaDeFin[8];
    char salon[10];
};

struct materias
{
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];
    struct actividades *actividad;
    struct fechasEspeciales *fechas;
    struct materias *siguiente;
};

typedef struct materias _nodoMaterias;
typedef struct fechasEspeciales _nodoFechasEspeciales;

_nodoMaterias *crearListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
bool listaVacia(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *insetarEnListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
void imprimirLista (_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *crearNodoMaterias(char nombre[], char profesor[], char tipoDeMateria[], char horasSemanales[]);
void datosAlumno();
_nodoMaterias *eliminarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
bool buscarMateria(char nombre[], _nodoMaterias *apuntador);
_nodoMaterias *modificarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador);
#endif //LISTAMATERIAS_H
```

y crear un archivo "listaMaterias.c"

```
 #include "listaMaterias.h"

//AQUI SE CREA LISTA Y SE PONE PARA QUE APUNTE A NULL
_nodoMaterias *crearListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    return (apuntador = NULL);
}

//ESTA FUNCION VERIFICA SI LA LISTA ESTA VACIA 
bool listaVacia(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    if (apuntador == NULL)
        return (true); //SI SALE EL TRUE SIGNIFICA QUE LA LISTA ESTA VACIA
    else
        return (false);//SI SALE EL FALSE SIGNIFICA QUE LA LISTA NO ESTA VACIA 
}

//AQUI SE CREA EL NUEVO NODO DE LA LISTA
_nodoMaterias *crearNodoMaterias(char nombre[], char profesor[], char tipoDeMateria[], char horasSemanales[])
{
    _nodoMaterias *registroNuevo;

    registroNuevo = (_nodoMaterias *) malloc(sizeof(_nodoMaterias));

    printf("\n----NUEVA MATERIA----\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nombre);
    while(!validarLetras(nombre))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",nombre);

        /*while(!buscarMateria())*/
    }
    printf("PROFESOR: ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%s",profesor);
    while(!validarLetras(profesor))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
        printf("\nPROFESOR: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",profesor);
    }
    printf("TIPO DE MATERIA: ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
    while(!validarLetras(tipoDeMateria))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS");
        printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
    }
    printf("HORAS SEMANALES:  ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
    while(!validarNumero(horasSemanales))
    {
        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
        printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
    }
    fflush(stdin);

        strcpy(registroNuevo->nombre, nombre);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->profesor, profesor);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->tipoDeMateria, tipoDeMateria);
        strcpy(registroNuevo->horasSemanales, horasSemanales);
        registroNuevo->siguiente = NULL;

    return registroNuevo;   

}

//AQUI SE INSERTA EL NODO EN LA LISTA LUGEO DE SER CREADO POR LA FUNCION crearNodo
_nodoMaterias *insetarEnListaMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *registroNuevo, *apuntadorAuxiliar;
    char respuesta,ch;
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];

    //ESTE CICLO SE ENCARGA DE QUE SE REPITA EL PORCESO PARA PODER INGRESAR MATERIAS HASTA QUE EL USUARIO DECIDA
    do
    {
            registroNuevo=crearNodoMaterias(nombre, profesor, tipoDeMateria, horasSemanales);
            if (listaVacia(apuntador)) 
                apuntador = registroNuevo;
            else
            {
                apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;
                while (apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente != NULL)
                    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
                apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = registroNuevo;
            }

            printf("\nPARA INGRESAR OTRA MATERIA MARQUE... 1");
            printf("\nPARA SALIR MARQUE... '0'\n");         
     while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');      

    scanf("%c", &respuesta);
        fflush(stdin);
   printf("RESPUESTA = %c", respuesta);             

    }while (respuesta == '1');
    return apuntador;
}

//TENGO QUE RIVAR BIEN LA FUNCION DE eliminarMateria PARA VER PQ NO ME ELIMINA LAS MATERIAS

_nodoMaterias *eliminarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    char materia[20];
    printf("\nQUE MATERIA DESEA ELIMINAR:  ");
    scanf("%s",materia);
    fflush(stdin);

    //INTENTO DE BORRAR NODO 1
    if (!listaVacia(apuntador))
    {
        _nodoMaterias *borrarAuxiliar;
        _nodoMaterias *anterior = NULL;

        while (apuntador != NULL)
        {
            /*anterior = borrarAuxiliar;
            borrarAuxiliar = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;*/
            if (strcmp(apuntador->nombre, materia) == 0)
            {
                anterior->siguiente = apuntador->siguiente;
                borrarAuxiliar = apuntador;
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
                free(borrarAuxiliar);
            }
            else
            {
                anterior = apuntador;
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
            }
        }
/*
        if (borrarAuxiliar == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nNODO NO ENCONTRADO");
        }else if (anterior == NULL)
            {
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
                free(borrarAuxiliar);               
            } else
                {
                    anterior->siguiente = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;
                    free(borrarAuxiliar);                   
                }*/
    }

    return apuntador;
}

_nodoMaterias *modificarMateria(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    char materia[20];
    printf("\nQUE MATERIA DESEA MODIFICAR:  ");
    scanf("%s",materia);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (!listaVacia(apuntador))
    {
        _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

        while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {           
            if (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL && strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) == 0)
            {
                char nombre[30];
                char profesor[30];
                char tipoDeMateria[20];
                char horasSemanales[10];

                printf("\nINGRESE LOS NUEVOS DATOS DE LA MATERIA");
                printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",nombre);
                while(!validarLetras(nombre))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
                    printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",nombre);
                }
                printf("PROFESOR: ");
                fflush(stdin);  
                scanf("%s",profesor);
                while(!validarLetras(profesor))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
                    printf("\nPROFESOR: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",profesor);
                }
                printf("TIPO DE MATERIA: ");
                fflush(stdin);  
                scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
                while(!validarLetras(tipoDeMateria))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS");
                    printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
                }
                printf("HORAS SEMANALES:  ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
                while(!validarNumero(horasSemanales))
                {
                    printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
                    printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
                }
                fflush(stdin);

                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, nombre);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->profesor, profesor);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeMateria, tipoDeMateria);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->horasSemanales, horasSemanales);
                apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = NULL;
            }

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }

    }
    else
        printf("\nLA LISTA ESTA VACIA");

    return apuntador;
}

//IMPRIMIR LOS NODOS DE LA LISTA
void imprimirLista (_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        printf("NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN LA LISTA \n");
    else
    {
        while(apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {
            printf(" \n------------MATERIAS-------------- ");
            printf("\nNOMBRE: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre);
            printf("\nPROFESOR: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->profesor);
            printf("\nTIPO DE MATERIA: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeMateria);
            printf("\nHORAS SEMANALES: %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->horasSemanales);

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    }

    return;
}

//ESTA FUNCION LE PERMITE SABER AL USUARIO LAS MATERIAS QUE INSCRIBIO 
void imprimirListaDeMaterias(_nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    int contador;

    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        printf("NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN LA LISTA\n");
    else
    { 
        contador = 0;
        printf("\nLISTA DE MATERIAS REGISTRADAS\n"); //AQUI VAN APARECIENDO LAS MATERIAS EN ORDEN ASI EL USARIO SABE CUALES DEBE SELCCIONAR
        while(apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {
            contador++;
            printf("%d", contador);printf(".- %s \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre);

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    }

    return; 
}

bool buscarMateria(char materia[], _nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
    }

    if (apuntadorAuxiliar == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Esto me parece que es correcto

Comment: Si es la respuesta que búscaste marcala por favor

Comment: es ilfredo quien pregunto, gracias por tu aportación +1.

Comment: Sí, es correcto, pero no aporta nada nuevo. Ni explica qué es lo que causa el error, ni como interpretar los mensajes de error para averiguarlo por ti mismo.

Comment: @eyllanesc entonces a todas mis librerias deberia ponerle guardas con sus respectivos nombres como me pusiste en esta?

Comment: @ilfredo exacto, si te sirvio mi ayuda marcala como la correcta

Comment: @eyllanesc no lo tengo separado ya que debo tener un menu y a su vez tengo otras operaciones que realizo segun mi menu

Comment: @ilfredo el último es un comentario para mantener un orden, primero prueba incluyendo guarda, lo segundo es opcional

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está pasando es que hay archivos de cabecera que se están incluyendo múltiples veces.

Por ejemplo :

```
//Archivo a.h
bool validar(int n);

//Archivo b.h
#include "a.h"
bool otra(int n);

//Archivo programa.c
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

bool validar(int n) {
  return false;
}

bool otra(int n) {
  return false;

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

El problema en los archivos anteriores es que programa.c incluye a.h

Pero también incluye b.h ; el cual a su vez incluye a a.h

Con lo que a.h queda incluido dos veces.

La solución es usar guardas de compilación :

```
//Archivo a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

bool validar(int n);
#endif //A_H

//Archivo b.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"
bool otra(int n);

#endif //B_H
```

Que esto es lo que está pasando se ve en los siguientes mensajes de error :

```
In file included from listaMaterias.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:5:
validacion.h:12:6: error: redefinition of ‘validarNumero’
 bool validarNumero(char numero[])
      ^
In file included from usario.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:4:
validacion.h:12:6: note: previous definition of ‘validarNumero’ was here
 bool validarNumero(char numero[])
```

listaMaterias.h incluye a validacion.h
usuario.h también inclye a validación.h

De ahí que todas las funciones definidas en validación.h salgan como repetidas.

Pon guardas de compilación a validación.h y queda solucionado. De hecho lo recomendable es poner guardas de compilación a todos los .h

Comment: Pues no, no es incorrecto. Si lo fuese, ¿podrías dar una explicación de lo que está mal?

Answer (score 1):

He editado mi respuesta, de acuerdo a lo que editaste en tu pregunta:

Tus archivos estan conteniendo referencias al archivo de cabecera `"validacion.h"`

Por ejemplo los archivos: `listaMaterias.h` y `usario.h` incluyen ambos el archivo de cabecera `validacion.h` por esa razón obtienes el error:

```
In file included from listaMaterias.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:5:
validacion.h:12:6: error: redefinition of ‘validarNumero’
 bool validarNumero(char numero[])
      ^
In file included from usario.h:5:0,
                 from menu.c:4:
validacion.h:12:6: note: previous definition of ‘validarNumero’ was here
 bool validarNumero(char numero[])
```

Revisa la propuesta de @eyllanesc en la cual sugiere el uso de 
`#ifndef` y `#define` para evitar dobles definiciones de archivos de cabecera:

```
#ifndef ARCHIVO_HEADER
#define ARCHIVO_HEADER
```

Comment: se puede incluir las cabeceras, eso no genera el error